# How to append variable which defined in include makefile from command line?

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile include `local.mk` which define a variable `DEFS`. I hope to append that variable from command.

Here is what I have tried.

local.mk:

```
DEFS += -DVAR1
```

Makefile:

```
DEFS ?=
$(info ${DEFS})
include local.mk
$(info ${DEFS})

test:
    echo ${DEFS}
```

When I run:

```
make DEFS+=-DVAR2
```

I expect to get `-DVAR1 -DVAR2` but I only got `-DVAR2`.

How could I append `DEFS` variable instead of override it from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this should be possible done the way you are trying but I'm having trouble getting the details straight in my head at the moment.

That being said you can do this instead:

```
DEFS=-DVAR2 make
```

and get what you want (order aside)

```
$ DEFS=-DVAR2 make -f start.mk
DEFS=-DVAR2
DEFS=-DVAR2 -DVAR1
echo '-DVAR2 -DVAR1'
-DVAR2 -DVAR1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [override directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Override-Directive) in `local.mk`:

```
override DEFS += -DVAR1
```